# Usage of the word 'from' and 'between' in the sentence

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> The children are **from** the ages of five and fifteen.

> The children are **between** the ages of five and fifteen.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is very strange. *From the ages of five and fifteen* seems to suggest the children are from only two age groups, 5 years and 15 years.

I would recommend this instead:

> The children are **from** the age of five **to** fifteen.

Your second sentence is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Of your two examples, the second is better.

A more idiomatic version of the first might be "The children's ages range from five to fifteen".